# Transfer Minecraft PE world from broken device

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son's tablet broke and when he gets a new one he is hoping he will be able to access all his saved worlds on his new device. Is this possible? Will the minecraft servers have his data saved if he re-installs his already purchased app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minecraft PE does not save information on servers, it saves it on the device's local storage. If he was playing on an Android with removable storage, the transfer is as simple as using the old card in the new device.

If the old broken device can still open Minecraft then you can transfer the world by hosting a LAN game from it, joining it with the new device and hitting `Quit and Copy World` in the Pause menu.

If not, you'll have to transfer the data across using a USB cable via a computer. If the old device is broken to the point where this won't work, there's not much you can do I'm afraid.

Comment: If an iOS device, there may be backups in iTunes if recently synced, or in iCloud if that was turned on.

Comment: Fredly, I tried doing this from an iPad world I created, to try and transfer the world onto my iPhone 4s. I was able to be on the world on both devices, but when I went into the pause menu on the iPhone that I wanted to "quit and copy world" to, the pause menu only had the typical "back to game", "options", and "quit to title" in the pause menu, not a "quit and copy world". Thanks for any help!